# How to find the index of closing parenthesis when the index of starting parenthesis and a String is given java program

Tags: java, string, parsing

when the string is  (A+b+(c+d)+(a))

Here the Index i: 0
Corresponding closing parenthesis: 14

Comment: One approach is by writing code.

Comment: What are you *actually* tying to do? I'm quite sure it *isn't* finding the index of a character in a String. Are you trying to get the balanced-bracketed part of the string that starts at index i?

Comment: @Bohemain Index of closing paranthesis..

Comment: So your code ends there, once you have the index of the closing bracket. You don't do anything more?

Comment: @Bohemain yes,the task of function ends with this. i'm stuck with the function of finding index of closing parenthesis,

Comment: @user3569504 It's not random comment, you should probably visit the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what questions should be asked here.

Comment: @user3569504 - This is how SOF works. I don't see anything wrong with Maroun's comment.

Comment: personally I think this a reasonable question, its clearly defined and a numebr of possible solutions.

Comment: @Advaitha. I think you , it can help you , https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179471/find-the-corresponding-closing-parenthesis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) to store parenthesis and iterate through the string...a stack is lifo, so should make getting the closing parenthesis easy. Soemthing liek this :

```
char[] myArray = exampleString.toCharArray()
for(int i = startIndex;i<myArray.length;i++){
    if(myArray[i] == "("){
      myStack.push(myArray[i]);
    }
    if(myArray[i] == ")"){
      myStack.pop();
    }
    if(myStack.empty()){
      return i;// the closing index of parenthesis
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is excellent..

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Start from your index. increment your count of "(" to 1. 
2. Now, for each "(" you encounter, increment count by 1.
3. For each ")" decrement count by 1.
4. If count ==0, that's your closing brace.
```

Comment: glad I could be of help :)